# Allowing function overloading in C compiler (Suppressing "conflicting types for " Error in C)

Tags: c, gcc, bison, cc

Let's say I have this C code that has two different declarations in C.

```
struct pcdata
{
    int x; int y;
};

int yyparse (struct pcdata *pp);
int yyparse (void *pp);

int yyparse (struct pcdata *pp)
{

}
```

Compiling the code with cc/gcc, I have `conflicting types` error.

```
test> cc -c hello.c
hello.c:7:5: error: conflicting types for 'yyparse'
int yyparse (void *pp);
    ^
hello.c:6:5: note: previous declaration is here
int yyparse (struct pcdata *pp);
^
1 error generated.
test> gcc -c hello.c
hello.c:7: error: conflicting types for ‘yyparse’
hello.c:6: error: previous declaration of ‘yyparse’ was here
```

There is no error with g++ as c++ allows function overloading.

```
test> g++ -c hello.c
```

Is there any gcc option to allow function overloading? I have this (simplified) code with Bison 2.7 generated tab.c code.

Comment: Why do you need 2 function definitions for `yyparse()`

Comment: If you want the C++ feature of function overloading, use C++ to compile the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That certainly won't work in C, but it shouldn't be necessary.

bison normally creates a `yyparse` which takes no arguments at all, but you can use the `%parse-param` declaration (at least in versions of bison which are not too old) to tell bison what arguments you want it to take.

In all cases, there is only one `yyparse` unless you have two separate parsers compiled into the same program, which of course can happen when you have more than one grammar which needs to be parsed. In this case, you can use `%name-prefix` to tell bison that one or both of the bison-generated parsers should use a prefix other than `yy`.

Comment: Actually, I got something wrong in this. I added another post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518961/parse-param-struct-pcdata-pp-issue-with-bison-2-7

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't have function overloading.