# Circular dependency resolution with bison generated file

Tags: c, gcc, bison

I have this code block in bison's yacc file. This is the code from the flex/bison code for [Flex & Bison](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596155988.do) book. The yacc code can be downloaded from https://github.com/GrooveStomp/Flex-Bison/blob/master/samples/purecalc.y

```
%{
#  include "purecalc.lex.h"
#  include "purecalc.h"
#define YYLEX_PARAM pp->scaninfo
%}
```

The issue is that I have a compilation error([Circular dependency resolution with bison generated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518961/parse-param-struct-pcdata-pp-issue-with-bison-2-7)); they are circular dependent as `purecalc.lex.h` depends on pcdata which is in purecalc.h file, whereas purecalc.h depends on purecalc.lex.h for yyscan_t.

yyscan_t is defiend in purecalc.lex.h:

```
typedef void* yyscan_t;
```

pcdata is defined as follows:

```
/* per-parse data */
struct pcdata {
  yyscan_t scaninfo;        /* scanner context */
  struct symbol *symtab;    /* symbols for this parse */
  struct ast *ast;      /* an AST for  */
};
```

How can I break this code dependency? I tried to copy the `typedef void* yyscan_t;` into the yacc source, but I got compilation error for duplicating typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some time in recent bison history, an incompatible change was made to the skeleton files, causing `yyparse` to be declared much earlier, in fact before the inclusion point for `%{ %}` sections. So `yyparse` is being declared before `purecalc.h` is included, which means that `pcdata` is not declared yet when `yyparse` is declared.

A simple solution would be to move the `#include purecalc.h` earlier, but this creates a different problem. The actual definition of `pcdata` requires `yyscan_t` which is declared in `purecalc.lex.h`. `purecalc.lex.h` requires that `YYSTYPE` be #defined, which happens in `purecalc.tab.h`. And `purecalc.tab.h` declares `yyparse`, which requires the declaration of `pcdata`.

The circularity can only be resolved by forward declaring:

```
struct pcdata;
```

But that has to happen before `purecalc.tab.h` is #included.

So one possibility would be to put these three lines early `purecalc.h`:

```
struct pcdata;
#include purecalc.tab.h
#include purecalc.lex.h
```

and then remove the redundant `purecalc.tab.h` and `purecalc.lex.h` includes from `purecalc.l` and `purecalc.y`, respectively. (Also, it would be a really good idea to be an include guard into `purecalc.h`).

Another possibility is to put `struct pcdata;` directly into `purecalc.y`. But it's not good enough to use a `%{ %}` block for that; it has to be inserted before `yyparse` is declared. For that, you need a `%code requires { }` block:

```
%code requires {
    struct pcdata;
}
```

I tried that, and it compiled with bison 2.7. If you were to use the first solution, you'd need to use a `%code requires { }` block for the `#include purecalc.h`, so it wouldn't look that different.